# how to print values in forloop untill loop is 1

Tags: android

how toprint for value inside forloop until value is reach to 1  is not print any thing tell me why what i did wrong? is not show anything in logcat help me please

```
                public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView    mytest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);



        for (int i = 31; i > 1; i--)
    {
          // System.out.println("hello "+i);
        mytest.setText(i);
           Log.d("SOMETHING", String.valueOf(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: `i < 1` will never be true.

Comment: this error comes  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1f

Comment: Somebody edited from `i < 1` to `i > 1` which is right now. If the code does now what it should do, please mark the correction as such and accept one of the answers below. Basically the're all right.

Comment: Please start a new question - and only post the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 31; i < 1; i--)
```

will never happens, so that the loop wont terminate you need

```
for (int i = 31; i > 1; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will execute as long as i is less than one (`i < 1`), which will never be true.  You should be testing for `> 1`.

```
for (int i = 31; i > 1; i--)
    {
          // System.out.println("hello "+i);
           Log.d("SOMETHING", String.valueOf(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `i < 1` is wrong try this:

```
for (int i = 31; i > 1; i--)
{
    // System.out.println("hello "+i);
    Log.d("SOMETHING", String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

error `i>1` should be there

```
for (int i = 31; i >1; i--)
    {
          // System.out.println("hello "+i);
           Log.d("SOMETHING", String.valueOf(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` is an Integer, but the `setText()` method requires a String. Try this:

```
mytest.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```